# diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path {PATH} already exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code:

```scala
    val outputFileName = inputFileName.concat("/result")
    val subDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(subRdd, tempResultDF.schema)
    tempResultDF.union(subDF).write.json(outputFileName)
```

When using `union` function, spark job fails to write the output.

> diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path {hdfs://outputFileName} already exists.

If I remove `union` function and just write the `tempResultDF`, it works well.

```scala
    val outputFileName = inputFileName.concat("/result")
    // val subDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(subRdd, tempResultDF.schema)
    tempResultDF.write.json(outputFileName)
```

Because I created subDF with tempResultDF schema, I didn't expect an error here.

Also, I don't understand the error log. It's about FileExist error, not the DF or function related one.

When tried with Overwrite option,

```
tempResultDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(outputFileName)
```

it occurs another error.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Any comment or link appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because `subRdd` format was different from `tempResultDF.schema`.
I changed `subRdd` to match `tempResultDF.schema` format, and the DF was written.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming outputFileName is a hdfs path ,could you pls check if that exists and try below

```
df.write.json.mode("")   //append or overwrite
```

Comment: When tried with `write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(outputFileName)`, it also occurs an error. I added logs on the question.